# Fetching An Array With MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an existing database which has a table called `PERSON` with a field called `NAME`. What I’m trying to do is select all of the rows in the table where the `NAME` is `"bill"`. And then I want the result to be stored in an array that I can step through at a later point.

Now, the problem is my code will only select the FIRST row with the name `"bill"` and ignore the rest of the rows where the `NAME` is `"bill"`. At least that’s how it appears when I print out the array contents with `print_r()`. My code below:

```
<?php
$getAllPreview = "SELECT * from PERSON where NAME = 'bill'";
$getAllResult = @mysql_query( $getAllPreview );
$getAllRows = @mysql_fetch_assoc( $getAllResult );

print "<pre>";
print_r($getAllRows);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: you need some sort of loop like `while()`, or `foreach()`

Comment: You should only use the `@` operator on StackOverflow if you explain why you are using it. Hiding notices, warnings and errors only makes it more difficult for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$getAllPreview = "SELECT * from PERSON where NAME = 'bill'";
$getAllResult = @mysql_query( $getAllPreview );
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc( $getAllResult ) ) {
  $getAllRows[] = $row;
}

print "<pre>";
print_r($getAllRows);
print "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is the only one which worked just how I wanted it to. Efficiency is important to me and Steven's answer hinted that his method is more efficient. I'm confused why I shoudn't use this solution?

Comment: @StevenNikolic this solution is fine. In fact, it's the best solution. StevenDon's solution is virtually identical to mine, except he didn't use the same variable you used in your original post. VarunSheth's solution is effectively the same, except for some reason he opted to use `mysql_fetch_array` with the `MYSQL_ASSOC` flag, which is *the same thing as using* `mysql_fetch_assoc`.  But my answer was posted first.  So why did I get downvoted? I'll tell you why: because some people like to downvote others' responses and upvote their own (with separate accounts) to promote their own.

Comment: It's a shameful practice that's rampant on SO

Comment: @CrayonViolent or maybe it's your hair lol its okay I upvoted you

Comment: Wow. I never would have thought a warm and fuzzy thing like people helping people for no material gain (that I know of) would result in such behaviour but then again one-upsmanship is a part of human nature. You may be right. At any rate your answer was clean, clear and precise so it works for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getAllResult, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 $data[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just keep looping over `mysql_fetch_assoc` until no further rows are returned. If you want to output or process them, just do so in each iteration of the loop, as it's more efficient than placing it in an array first. But here you go anyway:

```
$allRows = array ();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $getAllResult)) $allRows [] = $row;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

    $getAllPreview = "SELECT * from PERSON where NAME = 'bill'";
    $getAllResult = @mysql_query( $getAllPreview );


    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($getAllResult);

    while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($getAllResult)) 
    {

        for($i=0;$i<$num_rows;$i++)
        {

            $array[] = $row;

        }
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: This isn't going to do what you think it's going to do. It's going to create an array `$num_rows*$num_rows` size. where each row is in the array `$num_rows` times